# Object.entries() turning keys into arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm pulling in an object that, when I do a console.log(), returns data in this format:

```
{PerformanceYear:
  [{2020: "2020", checked: false}
   {2019: "2019", checked: true}
   {2018: "2018", checked: false}
   {2017: "2017", checked: false}
  ],
 Region: 
  [{1: "WA", checked: true}
   {2: "OR", checked: false}
   {3: "MT", checked: false}
   {4: "Other", checked: false}
  ],
 Service Area:
  [{5: "Northwest", checked: false}
   {6: "Southwest", checked: true}
   {7: "Southeast", checked: true}
   {8: "Other", checked: false}
  ],
}
```

(so the overall dataset is an object, not an array)

I'm trying to filter, but that can only be done on arrays, so I used Object.entries() to turn it into an array. The only problem is that each of PerformanceYear, Region, and Service Area *also* become their own separate arrays, so that when I try this:

```
var filtered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < entries[i][1].length; x++)
        if (entries[i][1][x].checked === true) {
            filtered.push(entries[i][1][x]);
        }
}
console.log(filtered)
```

I get this:

```
[{2019: "2019", checked: true},
 {1: "WA", checked: true},
 {6: "Southwest", checked: true},
 {7: "Southeast", checked: true}
]
```

What I *want* to get is this:

```
[PerformanceYear: {2019: "2019", checked: true},
Region: {1: "WA", checked: true},
Service Area: {6: "Southwest", checked: true}, {7: "Southeast", checked: 
true}
]
```

If I attempt filtered.push(entries[i][1]), it doesn't filter out the checked === false values. Is there a way to filter on the original object without turning it into an array? Or is there a way to turn the original object into an array without using array.entries()? I've been working on this for two days and am not seeming to make much progress. TIA!

Comment: That's an invalid js object

Comment: please add **valid data** and the **wanted result**, not only whyt you get.

Comment: As Ele mention this is not a valid object

Comment: I've been looking at this too long! My apologies; I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you want to keep the outer keys, you could get the entries and filter the arrays.

```js
var data = { PerformanceYear: [{ 2020: "2020", checked: false }, { 2019: "2019", checked: true }, { 2018: "2018", checked: false }, { 2017: "2017", checked: false }], Region: [{ 1: "WA", checked: true }, { 2: "OR", checked: false }, { 3: "MT", checked: false }, { 4: "Other", checked: false }], ServiceArea: [{ 5: "Northwest", checked: false }, { 6: "Southwest", checked: true }, { 7: "Southeast", checked: true }, { 8: "Other", checked: false }] },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, a]) => [k, a.filter(({ checked }) => checked)])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this did EXACTLY what I needed!!!