# Object.entries() removing the main key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I want to parse this dictionary:

```
var data = {'Charlie':
                    {'keys':
                        {'a': '1',
                        'b':['1', '2', '3'],
                        'c': '3'},
                    },
                'Derek':
                    {'keys':
                        {'a': '10',
                        'b': ['9', '8', '7'],
                        'c': '9'},
                    }
                };
```

But I want "Charlie" and "Derek" to appear as li names instead of Dummy. Still - I can't since I don't see them in response. They disappear after parsing, leaving:

```
'keys':
    {'a': '1',
     'b':['1', '2', '3'],
     'c': '3'}
```

and

```
'keys':
    {'a': '10',
     'b': ['9', '8', '7'],
     'c': '9'},
```

The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Div underneath</h3>
        <ul id="main-ul">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var data = {'Charlie':
                    {'keys':
                        {'a': '1',
                        'b':['1', '2', '3'],
                        'c': '3'},
                    },
                'Derek':
                    {'keys':
                        {'a': '10',
                        'b': ['9', '8', '7'],
                        'c': '9'},
                    }
                };

    lay_out_tab_structure(data)
    function lay_out_tab_structure(response) {
        console.log("response in lay_out_tab is", response)
        var ul = $('#main-ul');
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(response)) {
            var li = document.createElement('li')
            var div = document.createElement('div')
            li.append(div);
            ul.append(li);
            console.log("The key-value pair before passing is", (key, value))
            create_row(li, (key, value))
        }
    };

    function create_row(listItem, content) {
        console.log("Content in create row is", content)
        var mainDiv = $(listItem).children('div');
        var name = $('<p class="css-big-letter machine-name">'+'<a style="color:inherit;">'+"Dummy"+'</a>'+'</p>');
        var titleDiv = $('<div style="position:relative;margin-bottom:1%;"></div>');
        titleDiv.append(name);
        mainDiv.append(titleDiv);
        var RowDiv = $('<div></div>');
        $(mainDiv).append(RowDiv);
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Can you help me?

I have already tried this solution and I couldn't get it working:
[Object.entries() turning keys into arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437152/object-entries-turning-keys-into-arrays)

Comment: `create_row(li, (key, value))` will not do what you think it will. That will pass only `value` into the `create_row()` function. You probably want `[key, value]` to make an array, and then in `create_row()` the key will be in `content[0]` and the value in `content[1]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Pointy. Do you mind writing this to a proper answer so I could reward you with points and answered question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.entries()` will, as your code reflects, provide you with a list of 2-element arrays. Your code destructures each of those arrays into your `key` and `value` variables. All of that is fine.

However, when you want to pass both the key and the value to *another* function, you'll have to either pass each as a separate parameter, or else collect them back into a 2-element array. The statement

```
create_row(li, (key, value))
```

does not do either of those things. The expression `(key, value)` is a *comma expression* and will evaluate only to `value`, as you've found out. Thus, you could either change `create_row()` to accept a total of 3 parameters and pass `key` and `value` individually, or else group those two into a new array:

```
create_row(li, [key, value])
```

Either way will work. If you go with the array, then inside `create_row()` the key will be `content[0]` and the value will be `content[1]`.